# Handle high cardinality for one column in time-series database

Tags: time-series, monitor, prometheus

I have a very high cardinality time-series database. Suppose, I have 4 columns in my time-series database (A,B,C and D) whose individual cardinalities are (10, 100, 50, 10,000,000). So, in total I have a database of (10*100*50*10,000,000) cardinality. I want to know following questions:

1. Which alerting system should I use to monitor high cardinality
   (say 5 million cardinality in last one hour of data) database.
2. What is the best way to handle if 1 column in time-series database
   is of very high cardinality?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want use some sort of monitoring system where upon some events the system is triggered to alarm about a certain service right? like a anomaly detection system.

So, my question to you is, are you looking a monitoring tool, just to have reports overs the features, or use the time-series for machine learning for example?

I'll answer this as if it was oriented to Machine learning. I'm sorry if this is not your intention:

==> In ML features with high cardinality are usually handled through bining if you need usem as dummy variables. In orther words, for each level of the feature a new binary column is created. (Example: http code: 200, 200, 201, 404, 409, 500 ==> 2xx, 3xx, 4xx).

==> However, if you are using tree-based algorithms to handle high cardinality, no need for dummy variables to handle de cardinality.

Many more approaches can be used, but i need to know if this is what you are looking for in order for me to deepen the answer.